# Align layout to the bottom of the screen when using a scroll view and adding programmatically views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a form with a bunch of relative layouts, each one representing a group.
These are of two kind. One is the filter area which contains a spinner to choose a filter and an edit box for the input from the user and there can be multiple ones. The other kind has only one instance and contains a button that adds the aforementioned kind. This is aligned with the bottom of the parent which is a relative layout that contains all the others. This is also contained into a scroll view so it scrolls when the number of filter areas make the height bigger than the screen. My problem is that once I add enough filter areas to exceed the height of the screen the button gets moved once out of screen, then when you scroll down and press it again to add another one the button stays there. It's like the relative layout doesn't grow any more. 
Is it something I have to set up in the xml?

The original xml is the following:

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"> <!--IMPORTANT otherwise backgrnd img. will not fill the whole screen -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/searchLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.kadis.materialref.Search">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/controlArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/controlAreaHeight"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dividerControl2"
            style="@style/Divider"/>

        <Button
            style="@style/AddButton"
            android:id="@+id/addAttributeButton"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/addButtonWidth"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dividerControl2"
            android:onClick="addFilter"
            android:text="@string/addSearchAttributeString"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/filterArea0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/filterLayoutHeight"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/filterArea">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/filterOperatorSelector0"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/operatorSpinnerWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/filterSpinnerHeight"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/filterAttributeSelector0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/filterSpinnerHeight"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/filterOperatorSelector0"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/filterOperatorSelector0"/>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/filterInput0"
            style="@style/SearchFormFieldText"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/filterAttributeSelector0"
            android:text="Hello World"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the initial screen when first opening it.

[image: Initial screen when opening the app]

The code for the screen is the following.

```
public class Search extends Activity
{

    private String[] filterAttributes;

    private String[] filterOperators;

    private Spinner originalAttributeSelector;

    private Spinner originalOperatorSelector;

    private int lastAddedFilterAreaId;

//  private MultiSelectionSpinner multiSpinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        lastAddedFilterAreaId = R.id.filterArea0;

        // Get window sizes
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int displayWidth = dm.widthPixels;

        // Get items in spinners (attributes to search on an doperators to apply).
        filterAttributes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.attributes);
        filterOperators = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.operators);
//        multiSpinner = (MultiSelectionSpinner) findViewById(R.id.FilterSpinner);
//        multiSpinner.setItems(filterAttributes);

        originalOperatorSelector = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.filterOperatorSelector0);

        // Add items on the spinner.
        ArrayAdapter<String> operatorSpinnerAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_item_material_ref, filterOperators);
        operatorSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        originalOperatorSelector.setAdapter(operatorSpinnerAdapter);


        // Fix the width of the spinner so it doesn't get resized when making selections.
        // Get the screen width and subtract the width of the button next to the spinner.
        originalAttributeSelector = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.filterAttributeSelector0);
        originalAttributeSelector.getLayoutParams().width = displayWidth - originalOperatorSelector.getWidth();

        // Create the adapter containing the list of choices for the spinner (as well the style for it)
        // and bind it to the spinner.
        ArrayAdapter<String> attributeSpinnerAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_item_material_ref, filterAttributes);
        attributeSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        originalAttributeSelector.setAdapter(attributeSpinnerAdapter);

        originalAttributeSelector.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                // Make the selected text of the spinner slide.
                view.setSelected(true);

                // Get container, the RelativeLayout.
                RelativeLayout filterArea = (RelativeLayout) parent.getParent();
                // Get input element, EditText.
                View filterInput = filterArea.getChildAt(filterArea.getChildCount()-1);

                // Disable the add button if the selected values is the first (Please make a selection)
                if (id == 0)
                {
                    ((EditText) filterInput).setText("");
                    filterInput.setEnabled(false);
                } else
                {
                    findViewById(R.id.filterInput0).setEnabled(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void addFilter(View view)
    {
        // New Relative Layout to be added.
        RelativeLayout filterLayout = createFieldArea();

        // Add the operator spinner to the filter layout.
        Spinner filterOperatorSelector = createFilterOperatorSelector();
        filterLayout.addView(filterOperatorSelector);

        // Add the attribute spinner to the filter layout, next to the operator spinner.
        Spinner filterAttributeSelector = createFilterAttributeSelector(filterOperatorSelector);
        filterLayout.addView(filterAttributeSelector);

        // Add an Edit Text as the placeholder for the user input in the filter layout, below the attribute spinner.
        EditText filterInput = createFilterInputField(filterAttributeSelector);
        filterLayout.addView(filterInput);

        // Adding the whole filter layout to the search layout (whole screen)
        RelativeLayout searchLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.searchLayout);
        searchLayout.addView(filterLayout);

        RelativeLayout controlArea = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.controlArea);
    }

    private RelativeLayout createFieldArea()
    {
        // Generate id for new relative layout to be created.
        int filterLayoutId = MiscUtils.generateViewId();

        RelativeLayout filterLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        filterLayout.setId(filterLayoutId);

        // Define width and height parameters.
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.filterLayoutHeight));

        // Define position
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastAddedFilterAreaId);
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        filterLayout.setLayoutParams(rlp);

        // Update which is the latest added filter layout
        lastAddedFilterAreaId = filterLayoutId;

        return filterLayout;
    }

    private Spinner createFilterOperatorSelector()
    {
        Spinner filterOperatorSelector = new Spinner(this);
        filterOperatorSelector.setId(MiscUtils.generateViewId());

        // Add items on the spinner.
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_item_material_ref, filterOperators);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        filterOperatorSelector.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        // Define width and height parameters.
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlpSp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.operatorSpinnerWidth),
                getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.filterSpinnerHeight));

        // Define position
        rlpSp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        rlpSp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);

        // Set layout parameters
        filterOperatorSelector.setLayoutParams(rlpSp);

        return filterOperatorSelector;
    }

    private Spinner createFilterAttributeSelector(Spinner filterOperatorSelector)
    {
        Spinner filterAttributeSelector = new Spinner(this);
        filterAttributeSelector.setId(MiscUtils.generateViewId());

        // Add items on the spinner.
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_item_material_ref, filterAttributes);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        filterAttributeSelector.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        // Define width and height parameters.
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlpSp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.filterSpinnerHeight));

        // Define position
        rlpSp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
        rlpSp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        rlpSp.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, filterOperatorSelector.getId());
        rlpSp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, filterOperatorSelector.getId());


        // Set layout parameters
        filterAttributeSelector.setLayoutParams(rlpSp);

        return filterAttributeSelector;
    }
    private EditText createFilterInputField(Spinner filterAttributeSelector)
    {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) filterAttributeSelector.getParent();

        EditText filterInput =
                (EditText) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.search_attribute_input, null);
        filterInput.setId(MiscUtils.generateViewId());

        // Define width and height parameters.
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlpET = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        // Define position
        rlpET.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        rlpET.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
        rlpET.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        rlpET.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
        rlpET.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, filterAttributeSelector.getId());

        // Set layout parameters
        filterInput.setLayoutParams(rlpET);

        return filterInput;
    }

}
```

When I add the first layout that fills the screen and after I scroll down to find the button.
[image][image]

If I press the add button here nothing changes. I know from the debugger that the new layout was created so I am guessing it's out of the screen.

Comment: Hmm, maybe when adding programmatically another relative layout I should somehow resize the size of the layout myself? Maybe it doesn't grow by itself and I have to explicitly do it. I know how tall every layout I add is... I am going to try it while waiting for any responses.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. At least the way I did it.
searchLayout.getLayoutParams().height = searchLayout.getLayoutParams().height + filterLayout.getHeight();

Comment: Why don't you create this logic with a ListView? If you want another item, just add a new Item to your List<Item> and update your ListAdapter providing that new List<Item> and call notifyDataSetChanged(). Add the "add" button as footer to the List.